# figuring out an error

Tags: scheme, racket

I asked a few days ago how I would develop a function `one` which would consume a list of symbols and return the same list but with every instance of `cat` doubled.

so for example

```
 (one (cons 'animal(cons 'table (cons 'cat (cons 'bread
        empty)))))
```

I would get

```
(cons 'animal (cons 'table (cons 'cat (cons 'cat (cons 'bread 
    empty)))))
```

heres my part

```
(define (one alos)
  (cond [(empty? alos)empty]
        [(symbol=? 'cat (first alos)) (cons (first alos) (cons (first alos) (one rest alos)))]
         [else (cons (first alos) (one rest alos))]))
```

I am wondering why I keep getting 'one: expects only 1 argument, but found 2' ?

Comment: If you are using DrRacket, do you get any useful red highlighting around the problematic expression `(one rest alos)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a couple of parenthesis, this should fix it:

```
(define (one alos)
  (cond [(empty? alos) empty]
        [(symbol=? 'cat (first alos))
         (cons (first alos) (cons (first alos) (one (rest alos))))]
        [else (cons (first alos) (one (rest alos)))]))
```

Notice that you were recursively calling `one` like this:

```
(one rest alos)
```

But the correct way to call it is this:

```
(one (rest alos))
```

Answer (score 2):

Look here:
`[(symbol=? 'cat (first alos)) (cons (first alos) (cons (first alos) (one rest alos)))]`
and here:
`[else (cons (first alos) (one rest alos))]))`

What is `one` called with?